# nsxmlparser not solving &apos;

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, xml-parsing

Im using NSXMLParser to dissect a xml package, I'm receiving &apos inside the package text.

I have the following defined for the xmlParser:

```
[xmlParser setShouldResolveExternalEntities: YES];
```

The following method is never called

```
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundExternalEntityDeclarationWithName:(NSString *)entityName publicID:(NSString *)publicID systemID:(NSString *)systemID
```

The text in the field before the &apos is not considered by the parser.

Im searching how to solve this, any idea???

Thanks in advance
Alex

XML package portion attached:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?><SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:tns="urn:appwsdl"><SOAP-ENV:Body><ns1:getObjects2Response xmlns:ns1="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><return xsi:type="tns:objectsResult"><totalRecipes xsi:type="xsd:string">1574</totalObjects><Objects xsi:type="tns:Item"><id xsi:type="xsd:string">4311</id><name xsi:type="xsd:string"> item title 1 </name><procedure xsi:type="xsd:string">item procedure 11......
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I did, after referring a different answer from here.
I replaced all the occurrences of the `&apos;` in the xml with `"'"` when the data is received from NSURLConnection object. Then I give that data to the parser.

So what I do is:

```
NSData* parserData = [self resolveHTMLEntities: self.receivedData];
NSXMLParser* parser = [[NSXMLaParser alloc] initwithData:parserData];
```

Here is the resolveHTMLEntitites method:

```
NSString *xmlCode = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSMutableString *temp = [NSMutableString stringWithString:xmlCode];

// Replace all the entities
[temp replaceOccurrencesOfString:@"&amp;apos;" withString:@"'" options:NSLiteralSearch range:NSMakeRange(0, [temp length])];

NSData *finalData = [temp dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
return finalData;
```

The catch is that `&apos;` gets converted to `&amp;apos;` thats why we need to replace that occurrence.

Note: No memory management is performed in the above block of code.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

The standard entities are `&lt;`, `&gt;`, `&amp;`, and `&quot;`.  `&apos;` is an html entity reference.  Does your XML refer to the XHTML namespace or some other namespace that has `&apos;` defined?

(BTW, would be nice to see a small segment of the XML including the header.)

Comment: I atached the XML portion, and the parser is doing the same with the &amp, thanks a lot for you help.

Comment: I'm away from my Mac so I can't run a test at the moment, but have you tried `foundInternalEntityDeclarationWithName`?

Comment: Yes, I tried all the entity related delegates and no one is called :( 
Thanks a lot Epsilon :)

Comment: Looks like three20 uses resolveExternalEntityName to fill in the list of entities to parse:

http://github.com/facebook/three20/blob/8183ae25528bbc575ab41a41227756f06c166240/src/NSStringAdditions.m